# NuGet direct project references as versioned dependencies

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, nuspec

I have 2 Projects Libraries in my Example Solution > Visual Studio.
I directly reference one of them in the other. When I now publish my nuget package, on the dependency overview I get that my directly referenced nuget is `>= 1.0.0.0`, when I do it via nuget the reference means no direct reference because same solution I get the right version number under >= dependency overview. I won't change the default dependency behavior `lowest`.
What I've tried is to update my nuspec file with dependencies / references / files elements none of them worked for me.
I would like to see the same version of the given nuget in the directly referenced nuget as dependency.

Answer (score 9):

From the last sentence in you question and your emphasis on **direct references** makes me feel I know what you are after:

**NuGet defines the `-IncludeReferencedProjects` option to instruct `nuget.exe` how it should treat referenced projects, either as dependencies or as part of the package:**

- If a referenced project has a corresponding `.nuspec` file that has the same name as the project, then that referenced project is added as an explicit NuGet dependency.
- Otherwise, the referenced project is added as part of the package.

My guess is that you are after the former.

Let us simplify the problem to its most basic form: Let's say you have a solution where `LibraryA` references `LibraryB` directly as a project reference. When you build the solution, the assembly output from `LibraryA` is copied to `LibraryB`

```
~/
│   Solution.sln
├───LibraryA
│   │   ClassA.cs
│   │   LibraryA.csproj
│   │   LibraryA.nuspec
│   ├───bin
│   │   ├───Debug
│   │   │       LibraryA.dll
│   │   │       LibraryA.pdb
│   │   └───Release
│   └───Properties
│           AssemblyInfo.cs
└───LibraryB
    │   ClassB.cs
    │   LibraryB.csproj
    │   LibraryB.nuspec
    ├───bin
    │   ├───Debug
    │   │       LibraryA.dll
    │   │       LibraryA.pdb
    │   │       LibraryB.dll
    │   │       LibraryB.pdb
    │   └───Release
    └───Properties
            AssemblyInfo.cs
```

---

## Setup

> For illustration purposes I will use the pattern `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]` in my `AssemblyInfo.cs` files and will do a couple of separate builds on each project to ensure my assemblies get some different interesting versions.

**Make sure that each project contains a .nuspec file with the same name as the project.** This is specially important for project `LibraryA`, as it is the project being referenced by `LibraryB`. I'll do it for both as good practice. Let us use a basic template for now:

In the `.nuspec` below, the replacement tokens `$id$` and `$version$` will get their values **inferred** when you run `nuget.exe` against a `.csproj` file that has been built.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <authors>The author... (**mandatory element**)</authors>
    <description>Your description... (**mandatory element**)</description>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

---

## Use `nuget pack -IncludeReferencedProjects`

Now, I am going to run `nuget.exe` in the command line from the solution directory (`~`) on project `LibraryB`:

```
PS> nuget pack .\LibraryB\LibraryB.csproj -IncludeReferencedProjects -Verbosity detailed
    Attempting to build package from 'LibraryB.csproj'.
    Packing files from '~\LibraryB\bin\Debug'.
    Using 'LibraryB.nuspec' for metadata.
    Add file '~\LibraryB\bin\Debug\LibraryB.dll' to package as 'lib\net451\LibraryB.dll'

    Id: LibraryB
    Version: 1.0.5993.6096
    Authors: The author... (**mandatory element**)
    Description: Your description... (**mandatory element**)
    Dependencies: LibraryA (= 1.0.5993.7310)

    Added file 'lib\net451\LibraryB.dll'.

    Successfully created package '~\LibraryB.1.0.5993.6096.nupkg'.
PS>
```

---

## Generated packages

**The above command will create a NuGet package `LibraryB.1.0.5993.6096.nupkg` with a explicit NuGet dependency to `LibraryA.1.0.5993.7310.nupkg`.**

When you inspect the contents of `LibraryB.1.0.5993.6096.nupkg`, you will see that the `.nuspec` generated by `nuget.exe` will have replaced all the `$version$` replacement tokens to that of the actual versions used.

One last thing, the command above will create the NuGet package only for `LibraryB` but obviously you can create the one for `LibraryA` just by running it again targeting `LibraryA.csproj`

---

**I hope this is what you were after, or that at least sheds some light to what you can do.**